# How to rotate image/div in JavaScript in browsers other than IE

Tags: javascript, image, rotation

I need to rotate an image dinamically by angle specified by the user.

I use the following code, but it only works for IE and not for any other browser.

```
<div id="frame1" style="overflow:hidden" width='300' height='300'>
    <div id="frame2" width='200' height='200'>
        <img src='1.jpeg'' id='im' src='1.jpeg' width='10' height='10'>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

rotate(frame2, 45);

function rotate (elem, deg)
{
    if (navigator.appName=='Microsoft Internet Explorer')
    {
        rad = deg*Math.PI/180;

        elem.style.filter="progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11='1.0', sizingmethod='auto expand')";

        elem.filters.item(0).M11 = Math.cos(rad);
        elem.filters.item(0).M12 = -Math.sin(rad);
        elem.filters.item(0).M21 = Math.sin(rad);
        elem.filters.item(0).M22 = Math.cos(rad);
        elem.style.marginLeft=((canvsize-elem.offsetWidth)/2)+'px'
        elem.style.marginTop=((canvsize-elem.offsetHeight)/2)+'px'
    }
    else
    {
        elem.style.MozTransform    = 'rotate(' + deg + ')';
        elem.style.WebkitTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + ')';
        elem.style.OTransform      = 'rotate(' + deg + ')';
        elem.style.MsTransform     = 'rotate(' + deg + ')';
        elem.style.transform       = 'rotate(' + deg + ')';
    }
}

</script>
```

Can you please help?

Comment: Just FYI, browser detection is evil. Your code won't work in IE10 because `navigator.appName` equals to `'Microsoft Internet Explorer'` but support for filters was removed. Better check if some `*transform` attribute is present in `elem.style` and only if not, use filters fallback.

Answer (score 7):

Look at a CSS example:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
```

As you can see you forgot to add **deg**

```
elem.style.mozTransform    = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
elem.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
elem.style.oTransform      = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
elem.style.msTransform     = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
elem.style.transform       = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
```

Comment: the simplest explanations are always the best

Answer (score 0):

It's actually easier in browsers that aren't IE. The MDN has [good documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform) on how to do it with CSS3. There's some [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms) as well.

For Webkit browsers, [this page](http://tekkie.flashbit.net/css/css3-transforms-in-webkit) should help.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `deg` to the css property.

You should also add a `transform origin` to the image to make it rotate around the center (assuming that's what you're trying to do).

This code should do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<style>
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="frame1" style="overflow:hidden" width='300' height='300'>
    <div id="frame2" width='200' height='200'>
        <img src='1.jpeg' id='im' src='1.jpeg' width='10' height='10'>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

rotate(frame2, 45);

function rotate (elem, deg)
{
    if (navigator.appName=='Microsoft Internet Explorer')
    {
        rad = deg*Math.PI/180;

        elem.style.filter="progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11='1.0', sizingmethod='auto expand')";

        elem.filters.item(0).M11 = Math.cos(rad);
        elem.filters.item(0).M12 = -Math.sin(rad);
        elem.filters.item(0).M21 = Math.sin(rad);
        elem.filters.item(0).M22 = Math.cos(rad);
        elem.style.marginLeft=((canvsize-elem.offsetWidth)/2)+'px'
        elem.style.marginTop=((canvsize-elem.offsetHeight)/2)+'px'
    }
    else
    {

        elem.style.MozTransformOrigin = "5px 5px";
        elem.style.WebkitTransformOrigin = "5px 5px";
        elem.style.OTransformOrigin = "5px 5px";
        elem.style.MsTransformOrigin = "5px 5px";
        elem.style.transformOrigin = "5px 5px";

        elem.style.MozTransform    = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
        elem.style.WebkitTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
        elem.style.OTransform      = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
        elem.style.MsTransform     = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
        elem.style.transform       = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No problem. By the way, you might want to consider defining just one string to a variable, and then setting each property to the defined string variable. It makes it much easier to change values around in the future.